# How to configure Apache solr for daily logs

Tags: logging, solr, jetty, log4j2

I am using solr 4.10. It generates log files of format solr.log, solr.log.1, solr.log.2. I want that It should generate one file for each date. Can anyone guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use log4j. In the log4j.properties file include the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file
...

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=solr.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

To use log4j in logging, include the following in your solr.in.sh

```
LOG4J_PROPS=/path/to/log4j.properties
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

Add the entried in logging.proeperties which is at the folder apache tomcat/conf.

```
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = solr.
```

Register the handler at the top in the file where all the other handlers are :

```
6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

add the below entry at the last

```
org.apache.solr.level=INFO
org.apache.solr.handlers=6localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

you will get a seperate solr.log file with date where in you will have all the solr logs.

Along with this do check the documentation

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html

***rotatable*** - If true, the log file will be rotated on the first write past midnight and the filename will be {prefix}{date}{suffix}, where date is yyyy-MM-dd. If false, the file will not be rotated and the filename will be {prefix}{suffix}. Default value: true

Check whats the value for

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.rotatable = true
```

Comment: Just for your information, This version of solr uses jetty server and not tom cat. Please update answer according to jetty server.